# keeping non-responsive image on center horizontally

Tags: html, css

```
body{
    max-width:1366px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

.imgtop{
    display:block;
    width:1366px;
    margin:0 auto 5px auto;
}
```

I need `imgtop` always to be 1366px (not responsive), and centered horizontally on screen.

If the screen width is less than 1366px - `imgtop` should be cutted (i.e. hidden) on BOTH sides equaly, so keeping the center position.

Currently - on a smaller screens `imgtop` is cutted only on right side.

Any help?

Comment: You should use background-image instead of img tag, give background below props...

background-size:1366px auto;
background-position:top center;

Comment: seems the best solution, pls place as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by just a pinch of css like this...And you're all set...

```
background-size:1366px auto;
background-position:top center;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Align Center While Remaining Central

The below code will work nicely. Adjust to your project preferences.

[image]

```css
.myImage {
    height: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.myImage img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myImage"> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/PqKHozl.jpg" alt="Up" height="500" width="500"></div>
```

Comment: No, that's Stack Exchange CSS doing that, not the above code. If you copy my code into a file new file and rename something.htm you'll see it working as you described.

Comment: I've altered the code to make it cut both sides keeping in the center :)

Answer (score 0):

non responsive, yet always in the center (without the center tag)... you can change the image to any other image you'd like :)

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            nonResponsiveCenter();
            function nonResponsiveCenter(){
                var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
                            var imgWidth = $('img').width();
                            if (imgWidth > screenWidth) {
                                var widthDiff = -(imgWidth - screenWidth) / 2;
                                $('img').css("margin-left", widthDiff);
                            }
                            else {
                                var widthDiff = (screenWidth - imgWidth) / 2;
                                $('img').css("margin-left", widthDiff);
                                $('img').css("margin-right", widthDiff);
                            }
            }

            $(window).resize(function () {
                nonResponsiveCenter();
            });
        });
```

```css
    body {
        max-width: 1366px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .imgtop {
        display: block;
        width: 1366px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52585437/keeping-non-responsive-image-on-center-horizontally">Question</a>
    <br />
    <img src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/AkberIqbal.jpg">
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts, but I'm expecting a css solution for such a trivial thing.